# excel Delete rows from table Macro based on criteria

Tags: excel, vba

My Question: I am trying to delete rows in a table in column `AH` and Criteria is "Del" so any cell in column `AH`, I want to delete entire row in that table.

I tried so many different codes and most take forever as I have 10000+ rows to delete. I found this code from a site, but I am getting an error `subscript out of range Error9` from the `If Intersect` line:

```
Private Sub deleteTableRowsBasedOnCriteria(tbl As ListObject, _
                                           columnName As String, _
                                           criteria As String)

    Dim x As Long, lastrow As Long, lr As ListRow
    lastrow = tbl.ListRows.Count
    For x = lastrow To 1 Step -1
        Set lr = tbl.ListRows(x)
        If Intersect(lr.Range, tbl.ListColumns(columnName).Range).Value = criteria Then
            'lr.Range.Select
            lr.Delete
        End If
    Next x
End Sub
```

Then I called the sub as below:

```
Set tbl = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table4")
Call deleteTableRowsBasedOnCriteria(tbl, "AH", "Del")
```

Any help would be great. Thank you.

Comment: I finally got a chance to test this and my guess about the `.Range` was obviously completely wrong.  My next guess is ... does your table have a column labelled "AH"?  Or is that the Excel column?  (`tbl.ListColumns(columnName)` needs to have `columnName` contain the column name - e.g. "Column27" or "DelFlag" - whatever it is set up as in your table.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to just use `AutoFilter` instead of a loop. It is much faster.

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim rng As Range

    Set wks = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    Set tbl = wks.ListObjects("Table4")

    ' Filter and delete all rows that have "Del" in it
    With tbl.Range
        ' Switch off the filters before turning it on
        .AutoFilter
         ' Field:=34 must be equal to the column where you have the criteria in
        .AutoFilter Field:=34, Criteria1:="Del"

        ' Set the range for the filtered cells
        Set rng = .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        .AutoFilter ' Turn off the filter
        rng.Delete ' Delete the filtered cells
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, i just tried and i got an error "Autofilter Method of range class failed".  i think the reason is because its a table.

Comment: What is the name of the table range?

Comment: its called "Table4" Range is A5:AH

Comment: Take a look now. The error you are getting is referring to the `Field:=` which have to be the column number where AH and hence, Del is.

Comment: Ahh I can see you are using a Table ListObject, my bad. Will update the code to use that instead of a Named Range

Comment: @R.excel take a look now

Comment: Niclas. you are the man ... thanks a lot. code works perfect and under 3 min of calculation on a laptop, Great work thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

On large Datasets like this I prefer to use arrays instead of deleting rows.  The concept is pretty simple you load your `Target` cell values into an array (Data) and then create a second empty array the same size (NewData).  Next you loop through the Data and copy any rows of Data that you want to keep the next empty row in NewData.  Finally you overwrite the `Target` cell values with the NewData, effectively deleting the rows that you didn't want to keep.

I actually went a step further here by adding a `PreserveFormulas` parameter.  If `PreserveFormulas = True` then the formulas are copied to the NewData, instead of just the values.

Note: 59507 rows deleting every other row.  I compare Array Delete Data Only, Array Delete Preserve Formulas, Union Method and Filter Method.  [Download Test Stub](https://www.dropbox.com/s/x1cc1ukl3n5x0jq/excel%20Delete%20rows%20from%20table%20Macro%20based%20on%20criteria.xlsm?dl=0)

### Results

[image]

### Test

```
Sub Test()
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Set tbl = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1")
    Call deleteTableRowsBasedOnCriteria(tbl, "AH", "Del", False)
    Debug.Print
    Set tbl = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").ListObjects("Table13")
    Call deleteTableRowsBasedOnCriteria(tbl, "AH", "Del", True)
End Sub
```

### Code

```
Sub deleteTableRowsBasedOnCriteria(tbl As ListObject, columnName As String, criteria As String, PreserveFormulas As Boolean)
    Dim Start: Start = Timer
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Dim Data, Formulas, NewData
    Dim col As Long, pos As Long, x As Long, y As Long
    col = Columns(columnName).Column
    Data = tbl.DataBodyRange.Value
    If PreserveFormulas Then Formulas = tbl.DataBodyRange.Formula

    ReDim NewData(1 To UBound(Data, 1), 1 To UBound(Data, 2))

    For x = 1 To UBound(Data, 1)
        If Data(x, col) <> criteria Then
            pos = pos + 1
            For y = 1 To UBound(Data, 2)
                If PreserveFormulas Then
                    NewData(pos, y) = Formulas(x, y)
                Else
                    NewData(pos, y) = Data(x, y)
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next
    tbl.DataBodyRange.Formula = NewData
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Debug.Print "Preserve Formulas: "; PreserveFormulas
    Debug.Print "Original RowCount: "; UBound(Data, 1); " Column Count: "; UBound(Data, 2)
    Debug.Print "New RowCount: "; pos
    Debug.Print UBound(Data, 1) - pos; " Rows Deleted"
    Debug.Print "Execution Time: "; Timer - Start; " Second(s)"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I changed your code a little bit and added a button to execute the delete rows function. I use the buttons caption to display how many rows have been deleted so you know what is happening. The key is to call `DoEvents` so everything is refreshed and have the button caption changed while the rows are being deleted:

[image]

You add a button `CommandButton1` and try this code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim rowsDeleted As Long
Call deleteTableRowsBasedOnCriteria("H", "Del")

End Sub

Private Sub deleteTableRowsBasedOnCriteria(columnName As String, criteria As String)
    Dim x As Long, lastrow As Long, lr As ListRow, rowsDeleted As Long, deletedShift As Long
    lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    rowsDeleted = 0
    deletedShift = 0
    For x = lastrow To 1 Step -1
        If Cells(x, Range(columnName & 1).Column) = "Del" Then
            Rows(x).Delete
            rowsDeleted = rowsDeleted + 1
            deletedShift = deletedShift + 1

            If deletedShift >= 30 Then
                CommandButton1.Caption = "Deleted " & rowsDeleted & " rows"
                deletedShift = 0
                DoEvents
            End If
        End If
    Next x

    MsgBox "Total rows deleted: " & rowsDeleted
End Sub
```

Comment: FYI - instead of `Cells(x, Range(columnName & 1).Column)` you could just use `Cells(x, columnName)` - the column parameter of the `Cells` object can be a String such as "AH" (i.e. `Cells(25, "AH")` is valid syntax).

Comment: Thanks for the information. Didn't know that. I just searched how to convert a column letter to index because I thought `Cell` accepts only numeric indexes.

Comment: I have to admit that I had never thought to use a letter code for that parameter until I started frequenting SO.  For many, many years I was always just using a number - I just about know the conversion from "A...Z,AA..AZ" to 1..26,27..52 off by heart - all that brain space just wasted because I didn't have to do it that way.