# Efficient Loops in VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, loops, rows

I have written a VBA Macro which works, but takes too long because the database is also very big. 
I know this can be optimized via Arrays, but I am not sure how to make it. 
Could someone help me please?

```
'Identify how many rows are in the file
 finalrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Row

'fill the empty fields which requires the part number and description
For i = 2 To finalrow
    If Cells(i, 3) = 0 Or Cells(i, 3) = "------------" Or Cells(i, 3) = "e" Or Cells(i, 3) = "111)" Or Cells(i, 3) = "ion" Then
        If Cells(i, 4) = 0 Or Cells(i, 4) = "-----------" Or Cells(i, 4) = "Location" Then
            Range("A" & i & ":H" & i).Select
            Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
            i = i - 1
            Else
                For j = 1 To 3
                    Cells(i, j) = Cells(i - 1, j)
                Next
        End If
    End If
    If Cells(i, 1) = 0 Then
        Cells(i, 1) = Cells(i - 1, 1)
    End If

    If Cells(i, 4) = 0 Then
            Range("A" & i & ":H" & i).Select
            Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
            i = i - 1
    End If

    Count = Count + 1
    If Count = finalrow Then
        i = finalrow
    End If
Next
```

Comment: since it's a working code to be optimized, you might post it in [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Also add details about the actual aim of your code along with data examples of "before" and "after" scenarios

Comment: When deleting you should delete from the last row to the first row (e.g. `For i =  finalrow to 2 Step -1`).  You would have saved several lines of code and a lot of brainpower.  I have to commend you on your work around, though.  Very cleaver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I combined your code with my answer to [excel Delete rows from table Macro based on criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40686695/excel-delete-rows-from-table-macro-based-on-criteria/40690645#40690645), that I just finished posting.  It is super fast.  Please check out my other answer for details.

You may need to adjust the `Target` range.  If your data starts in `A1` and does not have any completely blank rows than it should work.

```
Sub DeleteRows()
    Dim Start: Start = Timer
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Const PreserveFormulas As Boolean = True
    Dim Target As Range
    Dim DeleteRow As Boolean
    Dim Data, Formulas, NewData
    Dim pos As Long, x As Long, y As Long
    Set Target = Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    Data = Target.Value

    If PreserveFormulas Then Formulas = Target.Formula

    ReDim NewData(1 To UBound(Data, 1), 1 To UBound(Data, 2))

    For x = 2 To UBound(Data, 1)
        DeleteRow = True

        If Data(x, 3) = 0 Or Data(x, 3) = "------------" Or Data(x, 3) = "e" Or Data(x, 3) = "111)" Or Data(x, 3) = "ion" Then
            If Data(x, 4) = 0 Or Data(x, 4) = "-----------" Or Data(x, 4) = "Location" Then
                DeleteRow = False
            End If
        End If

        If Data(x, 4) = 0 Or Data(x, 4) = "-----------" Or Data(x, 4) = "Location" Then DeleteRow = False

        If Not DeleteRow Then
            pos = pos + 1
            For y = 1 To UBound(Data, 2)
                If PreserveFormulas Then
                    NewData(pos, y) = Formulas(x, y)
                Else
                    NewData(pos, y) = Data(x, y)
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next
    Target.Formula = NewData


    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Debug.Print "Execution Time: "; Timer - Start; " Second(s)"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks I am happy to help.

Answer (score -1):

I'd start simply with this:

```
'Identify how many rows are in the file
 finalrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Row

'fill the empty fields which requires the part number and description
For i = 2 To finalrow
    Set ci3 = Cells(i, 3)

    If ci3 = 0 Or ci3 = "------------" Or ci3 = "e" Or ci3 = "111)" Or ci3 = "ion" Then
        Set ci4 = Cells(i, 4)

        If ci4 = 0 Or ci4 = "-----------" Or ci4 = "Location" Then
            Range("A" & i & ":H" & i).Select
            Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
            i = i - 1
            Else
                For j = 1 To 3
                    Cells(i, j) = Cells(i - 1, j)
                Next
        End If
    End If
    If Cells(i, 1) = 0 Then
        Cells(i, 1) = Cells(i - 1, 1)
    End If

    If Cells(i, 4) = 0 Then
            Range("A" & i & ":H" & i).Select
            Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
            i = i - 1
    End If

    Count = Count + 1
    If Count = finalrow Then
        i = finalrow
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Thanks,
Is not as fast as the answer from Thomas but is for sure better than the actual status and also solves a samall debug problem which I had some times.
thanks a lot for your reply!